# Put bean in to the map to get bean from factory by name

Tags: java, spring

I need to get the bean from the factory by name. 
I wonder if there is a more elegant way to deal with this problem? 
My working code now looks like this. This is my interface service and "factory"

```
public interface GreetingService {
    void getGreeting(String name);
}

public interface GreetingServiceFactory {
    GreetingService getGreetingService(String region);
}
```

Implementation greetingService:

```
  @Service
    public class EnglishGreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
        @Override
        public void getGreeting(String name) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        }
    }

    @Service
    public class GermanGreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
        @Override
        public void getGreeting(String name) {
            System.out.println("Willkommen " + name);
        }
    }
```

Implementation factory:

```
@Service
public class GreetingServiceFactoryImpl implements GreetingServiceFactory {

    private Map<String, GreetingService> greetingBeanMap;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("germanGreetingServiceImpl")
    private GreetingService germanGreetingService;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("englishGreetingServiceImpl")
    private GreetingService englishGreetingService;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init () {
        greetingBeanMap = new HashMap<>();
        greetingBeanMap.put("en", englishGreetingService);
        greetingBeanMap.put("de", germanGreetingService);

    }
    @Override
    public GreetingService getGreetingService(String region) {
       return  greetingBeanMap.get(region);
    }
}
```

Main class with example code where I receive bean after some name

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringFactoryApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingServiceFactory greetingServiceFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringFactoryApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    String config1 = "en";
    GreetingService english = greetingServiceFactory.getGreetingService(config1);
    english.getGreeting("John");

    String config2 = "de";
    GreetingService deutsch = greetingServiceFactory.getGreetingService(config2);
    deutsch.getGreeting("Hans");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do annoy you with your actual solution ?

Comment: GreetingServiceFactoryImpl requires modification when adding a new implementation GreetingService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your above code, this piece of code is completely redundant

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("germanGreetingServiceImpl")
 private GreetingService germanGreetingService;

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("englishGreetingServiceImpl")
 private GreetingService englishGreetingService;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init () {
        greetingBeanMap = new HashMap<>();
        greetingBeanMap.put("en", englishGreetingService);
        greetingBeanMap.put("de", germanGreetingService); 
 }
```

this piece of code can be replaced by

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, GreetingService> greetingBeanMap;
```

When you declare like this, spring will search for all implementations of `GreetingService` interface and inject into your map, with the key as the bean name. i.e. the greetingBeanMap will have key's as `germanGreetingServiceImpl` and `englishGreetingServiceImpl` and value as the bean's itself.

If you want to make the key's as "en" and "de" instead of bean names, then you can name the beans as "en" and "de". Like this

```
@Service("en")
public class EnglishGreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
 ......
}

@Service("de")
public class GermanGreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
 ......
}
```